# How to make an element strech to the same height as the content within it?

Tags: html, css

The header div's height will not stretch vertically to fit the content within it unless I specify a height for it or unless I stick one of these:

```
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

before the header div's closing tag.

```
<style type="text/css">
#header {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
</style>

        <div id="header">
            <span id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" /></span>
            <span class="fright">something will go here</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- header -->
```

Can this be done without the use of a "clearing div" or without giving the header div a fixed height?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#header { overflow: auto; width: 100%; }
```

It will clear past your floats without the extra element

Answer (score 0):

The only reason the clear would have an impact is if you are using floats. Can you post all of your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clearfix method to avoid having to use a clearing div. It's documented on [this site](http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack/).

```
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    }
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

Then all you have to do is give the div a .clearfix class.